# How to start IE with a URL in a CYGWIN session

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, ubuntu, windows-xp, cygwin

I have a windows xp machine set up with Cygwin running the ssh service, on that machine I have a bat script that opens up IE using the following command "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://windowsxpbox:3000/flex/flexUnitTests?debug=true#automated=true".

The script runs fine when I'm calling it locally on that xp machine, I am trying to call that same bat script remotely from another machine and achieve the same result but with IE opened on the remote machine, my problem is when the bat script is called remotely nothing happens on the remote machine.

Comment: aren't cygwin paths like /drive/c/....?

Comment: Tried that, got the same problem with this path "/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Internet\ Explorer/IEXPLORE.EXE"

Answer (score 20):

Just:

```
cygstart "http://www.google.com"
```

where google.com is your desired URL.

`cygstart` launches the default windows program for a path. So this way you get the user’s preferred web browser...

Comment: It seems that cygstart is using the `http` protocol prefix on the argument to determine that it is a URL on the internet and a web browser should be used to open it. To be explicit about using a web browser even when the prefix is lacking you can use `cygstart chrome google.com` (This command uses Chrome, not IE). You can also use this to open local files on your machine using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

cygstart /cygdrive/c/Programme/Internet\ Explorer/iexplore.exe "www.google.at"

path may change according to your installation

Answer (score -1):

Cygwin's shell doesn't know how to execute a batch script.  Use cygwin to start cmd.exe, and let that run the batch file. E.G.

```
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c "c:\myscript.bat"
```

Edit: if you'd rather run explorer directly rather than relying on a batch file, the following works properly for me:

```
$ "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe" "http://windowsxpbox:3000/flex/flexUnitTests?debug=true#automated=true"
```

Comment: thats not true, you can run batch scripts from the cygwin shell.

Comment: I just tested it myself and got an error, although it wasn't the error I expected.

Comment: My problem is not so much as calling a bat script remotely, but the problem is starting up IE remotely.

Comment: Cygwin is capable of running shell scripts, and some batch files might resemble shell scripts closely enough to run properly. If you're trying to do this explicitly, you should be aware of the differences and program accordingly.

Comment: I really do run batch scripts in cygwin, the startx comes in two flavours startx.sh and startx.bat and both are used to start up X